# Delete em mais de uma tabela com uma SQL?

Tags: java, mysql

Estou tentando aplicar um `DELETE` em mais de uma tabela, as tabelas possuem uma coluna (não com o mesmo nome) com os mesmo atributos. Quero deletar através do ID. Mas tenho a tabela `usuario` com coluna id e `areausuario` com coluna `idUsuario`, são os mesmos atributos (`id = 1`, `IdUsuario = 1`).

Estava tentando com este código.

```
DELETE us.*
FROM usuarios us
INNER JOIN disponibilidade ds ON (us.id = ds.IdUsuarios)
INNER JOIN areausuarios au ON (ds.IdUsuarios = au.IdUsuarios)
INNER JOIN gestor g ON (au.IdUsuarios = g.id)
WHERE g.id = 7;
```

Mas este código esta deletando somente de uma tabela.

Tentei alguns outros mas ele aplica o ***erro 1451***, onde eu não posso deletar o `usuario`, sem antes retirar ele da tabela `areausuarios`.

Answer (score 1):

### ON DELETE CASCADE.

A mensagem que diz que voce não pode "deletar o usuário sem antes retirar ele da tabela `areausuario`" indica que existe um relacionamento entre as duas tabelas através de uma chave estrangeira.

O que vc tem de fazer é exatamente isso, primeiro deletar o usuário da tabela `areausuario` e só depois excluir da tabela usuário. Na maioria dos bancos voce pode configurar o relacionamento de forma que ao deletar um um registro na tabela "pai", automaticamente os registros correspondente serão deletados na tabela "filho".

Veja como se faz em Mysql [nesse link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/).

Answer (score 1):

Suas tabelas estão relacionadas?
Existe `foreign key` na coluna `IdUsuario` na tabela `areausuario`?

Se sim, você pode utilizar o `on delete cascade`, como está explicado pelo @Sidon.

---

Senão, você pode executar duas queries distintas e depois efetuar o `commit`.

É possível utilizar o conceito de `transaction` para executar essas queries distintas e por fim executar o `commit`.

A pergunta tem as tags [java](/questions/tagged/java) e [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql), mas não possui código Java em seu corpo. Dessa forma fica difícil explicar detalhadamente como fazer, mas [aqui](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-transaction-example/) em tem um exemplo de como usar `transaction` com Java e MySQL.